# Minimisation of a multivariable function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, differentiation

```
import math
import numpy
import scipy

def chisq1a(a,b,NN):
return (NN/(a**2)*b**2*(1+3/(a**2))*(1+(math.tan((math.pi)/2*(a+b*math.log(b/0.45))))**2))

x0 = numpy.array([0,0,0])

from scipy.optimize import minimize
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(chisq1a, x0)
```

I am trying to minimise a multivariable function in Python 3 using the above code but I obtain an error that

```
  TypeError: chisq1a() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'NN'
```

What does this mean? This error has arisen before in the context of having subsequently written a function, initially defined with n arguments, as one with e.g n-1 arguments so there is a mismatch, but this does not seem to be the problem here. Probably the solution is simple but I just started with python a few days ago so still learning :) Thanks!

Comment: `chisq1a` should take all 3 parameters as an array and unpack.

Comment: @internet_user could you elaborate on what you mean by unpack?

Comment: @roganjosh there is b, but not NN indeed. I will introduce NN somewhere if it is required, this is just a toy function for this question on the forum (albeit maintaining the complexity of my actual function I'm dealing with)

Comment: @roganjosh Sure, but no where have I attempted to evaluate e.g chisq1a(1,2,3) for example. My only calling point of the function was of chisq1a in my attempt to minimize it. Here I didn't specify the arguments but I get an error only about b and NN (and not a), so something more is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `minimize` function was designed this way but it appears that you have to unpack the arguments inside the function which you want to minimise. I wasn't able to supply multiple arguments in any other way (for example, as a tuple). I took my cue from the bottom example [in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) where they use:

```
fun = lambda x: (x[0] - 1)**2 + (x[1] - 2.5)**2
```

as an example for multiple arguments, i.e. the single argument `x` which they then index inside the function. The fact that they use a `lambda` doesn't make a difference.

I had to update your initial guess from `[0, 0, 0]` to avoid a `ZeroDivisionError`. The following appears to work:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy

def chisq1a(x):
    a, b, NN = x
    return (NN/(a**2)*b**2*(1+3/(a**2))*(1+(math.tan((math.pi)/2*(a+b*math.log(b/0.45))))**2))

x0 = np.array([1, 1, 1])
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(chisq1a, x0)
```

As for accessing the results, the docs linked earlier state:

> res : OptimizeResult
>
> The optimization result represented as a OptimizeResult object.
>   Important attributes are: x the solution array, success a Boolean flag
>   indicating if the optimizer exited successfully and message which
>   describes the cause of the termination. See OptimizeResult for a
>   description of other attributes.

So, `x` is your result array that you can again unpack.

```
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(chisq1a, x0)
a, b, NN = result.x
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) What's the correct way to print out the results of the a,b,NN? Print(result) gives me something but I don't think I see the optimal parameters a,b,NN in there.

Comment: Thanks. I played about with the initial guess and I see the parameters it finds changes every time which might reflect lots of local minimum in the function. So I'm not sure if minimise attempts to stop the iteration after its found a local minimum or whether it searches for a global one. Do you know if this is the case? Otherwise I'll have a look in the documentation.

Comment: @CAF the documentation should be your first port of call anyway; there are multiple optional arguments that you're not using. In any case, your question was how to run the `minimization` code and hopefully my answer has solved that issue for you. If that is the case I would appreciate if you could mark it as accepted to close the issue.